# FFMPEGmediametadataretriever not getting all frames from video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, mediametadataretriever

I am developing an application that takes a local video file and extracts its frames and write on disk. I am using [`ffmpegmediametadataretriever`](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) to extract frames from videos. I have done the following code

```
   retriever.setDataSource(activity, uri);
   Log.e("duration -> ", retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
   long duration = Long.parseLong(retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
   int everyNFrame = 1;
   double frameRate = Double.parseDouble(retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_FRAMERATE));
   Log.e("all metadata", retriever.getMetadata().getAll().toString());
   long sec = Math.round(1000 * 1000 / (frameRate));
   Bitmap bitmap;
// Bitmap bitmap2;
// Log.e(" timeskip ", sec + "   -----------   " + (frameRate * 1000));
   for (long i = 1000; i < duration * 1000; i += sec)
// for (long i = sec; i < duration * 1000 && !stopWorking; i += sec)//30*sec)
// for(int i=1000000;i<duration*1000 && !stopWorking;i+=300000)
   {
       bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(i, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
       if (bitmap != null) {
          try {
                  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path + "/img_" + (i) + ".jpg");
                  Log.e("filename->", path + "/img_" + i + ".jpg");
                  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                  bitmap.recycle();
                  Thread.sleep(75);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
       }
    }
```

It is not extracting all the frames from the video. for some videos frames extracted are repeated. Random number of frames are extracted for different videos. for some videos, 70-80% frames are extracted and for some only 15-20 frames are extracted.

I have gone through all the answers I could find on StackOverflow and other websites to find a solution but the issue is there.

Comment: How many frames you get, I mean do you get 50% frames of your desired quantity or not any single frame ? kindly explain it more

Comment: i have updated the description. Random number of frames are extracted for different videos. for some videos, 70-80% frames are extracted and for some only 15-20 frames are extracted.

Comment: Same here, for 1-2 seconds sometimes does not extract any frame